# how to align more spans horizontly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to develop custom worksheet like, user can browse and upload more no of images inside particular div. That images should draggable inside that div only (I did it). There is two option before print the images, first one is unorder alignment print and second one is alignment print. So when user click on alignment button that all uploaded images should horizontically align one after one within that div.

The code I tried,

**css.**

```
.draggable { width: 90px; height: 80px; padding: 5px; float: left; margin: 0 0px 0px 0; font-size: .9em; }
.ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p { margin:0px } 
#snaptarget { height: 842px; width:595px;  border:2px solid green; padding: 10px;}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<Input type="button" value="align" onclick="alignment();"> 

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
<input type="button" id="p" value="print" onclick="printing();" align="right">
<p id="list"> </p> 

<div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">  </div>

<input type="text" value="0" id="textid">
```

**creating span dynamically with dynamic id using below code,**

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        var txtval=$('#textid').val();
        addplus1 = 1;
        txtval=parseInt(txtval)+parseInt(addplus1);
        //txtval+=addplus1;
        alert(txtval);
        $('#textid').val(txtval);
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.

                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<span id="s'+txtval+'" style=" width: 300px;"><ul id="un" class="img-list"><li onclick="getid(this)"><img id="img" class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                    '" title=" click this image for deselect" /><span class="text-content"><span>Click here to Drag</span></span></ul></span>'].join('');

                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f); 

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

**tried the alignment code,**

```
function alignment() {
    var lengthoftxt=$('#textid').val();

    for(var i=1;i<=lengthoftxt;i++)
    {
        $('#s'+i).each(function() {
            // $(this).css({"marginLeft": "opx"}); 
            $(this).css({"align": "horizontly"}); 
            //how to align horizontly one by one within that div???
        });
    }    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textid').val('0');
});
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/908/

where i am wrong? how to do this?

Comment: Instead of `marginLeft: 200px` in your fiddle add `float:left`

Comment: @anpsmn i tried $(this).css('float','left'); and $(this).css({float:left}); but no use!

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/46psK/914/). When you click align after uploading say two images, it aligns horizontally. Check with small images to know the difference.

Comment: its working but its moving over the div but i want to place horizontly only within the div.

Comment: You mean the div with green border? If yes then the list itself is never appended inside that div before alignment.

Comment: yes that green border. so is there any other option to make arrange orderly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65262/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-anpsmn).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the working you wanted

The `p#list` was outside `#snaptarget` hence the newly created items were placed outside. Bring the p tag inside `#snaptarget`

```
<div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">
     <p id="list"></p>
</div>
```

The below js code was setting float to spans with ids but all these spans had  another span as a wrapper hence the floats never worked as intended.

```
$('#s' + i).each(function () {

     $(this).css({
          "float": "left"
      });
});
```

You can add a class say `item` while creating the span.

```
 var span = document.createElement('span');
 span.className = "item";
```

And in alignment function add a class say `float-left` to all spans having class `item`

```
 $('.item').addClass('float-left');
```

And in CSS

```
.float-left{ float: left}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/46psK/917/)

Comment: its working fine but when drag and drop and again click on align button that dragged images not align left!why?

Comment: Can you show me the drag and drop issue with a fiddle?

Comment: I tried to show in fiddle but its not run in fiddle but drag is run my system.

Comment: my problem is after drag images to some place and click on align button it nothing happen, actually whenever i click align all images should align ordely.how?